# Can I cascode 2 positive LDOs generate both positive and negative power rails?

Tags: ldo

I looked [this](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/easy-split-voltage-power-supply-for-analog-circuits-draws-only-720na.html) circuit:

[image]

I have a idea,

Can I cascode 2 positive LDOs generate both positive and negative power rails?

For instance, the input is 5.1 Vusb, I cascode 2 [TPS7A2050](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps7a20) generating +/-5V:

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: Trace a current through a load between +5 and -5 in your diagram, bypassing the ground reference. Just a direct load between the two *not-ground* rails. What do you see by way of the current path?

Comment: Also try tracing current flow from the USB supply (pin 1) through your proposed circuit and back to the supply (pin 2). Remember that your LDOs are *linear* regulators, so for the purpose of this thought experiment you could replace each one with a pair of resistors (one from IN to OUT, and another from IN to GND).

Comment: What you want is an inverting boost converter. - these can increase the voltage. As the others have mentioned, linear regs can drop voltage but not increase voltage. They regulate by varying the loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As you say, they are LDOs.

The positive one does not have the headroom to regulate 5 V from 5 Vusb, unless you know for certain that the usb input voltage never drops below 5.1 V. 4.5 V might be a better positive output target.

The negative one cannot generate -5 V, unlike the LTC3388 which is a switching converter, not an LDO. In a switching converter, the inductor stores energy which, in the configuration shown for the 3388, can push current out at a negative voltage, creating the negative rail. An LDO does not have any mechanism like this, it only regulates between the rails that are supplied to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why it is not possible with LDOs? Or provide a resource where this is explained. Out of curiosity.

Comment: @Marco I'm not sure I know how to answer that, without knowing exactly what level of model the person asking the question needs. To me, it's either obvious, or it isn't.